# Python OpenCV веб камеры не считывает QR code

Tags: python, opencv

с помощью веб камеры и библиотекой pyzabar пытаюсь распознать содержимое QR кода, веб камера видит QR код но распознавание не происходит, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, ниже приведен код

```
def qr_webcam_reader():
ret, frame = capture.read()
if ret:
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (400, 280))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(img)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    LabelCamera.imgtk = imgtk
    LabelCamera.configure(image=imgtk)
for code in decode(frame):
    decoded_data = code.data.decode("utf-8")
    rect_pts = code.rect

    if decoded_data:
        pts = np.array([code.polygon], np.int32)
        cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(frame, str(decoded_data), (rect_pts[0], rect_pts[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
win.after(10, qr_webcam_reader)
```